# How to put input fields on the left side and text labels on the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, label

If you're making a form, you'd normally place the text label on the left side and the input field on the right side.

Thought I want it to be the other way around: I want that the input fields stay on the left side of the labels, which are on the right side.

How can I implement it?

Comment: why would you want that? It's not good for usability, people's eyes scan from left to right when they read (in most parts of the world) and so the labels are on the left, so that you read the label before filling out the form.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers But what if he is from Asia? There they read from right to left

Comment: true, and although I've never been on an asian site, so I could be wrong there, I think that most sites just leave their positioning the western way.

Comment: I'm not working on a form, but a list for costumers to fill in, so i need to have the fields on the left.

Comment: just put the input elements before their labels :O If you still have a problem, see http://jsfiddle.net/tGw2K/. you may be intersted in CSS direction:rtl; property too for setting text direction right-to-left.

Comment: @Dandroid: I'm in Asia... I sure as hell don't read most things right to left (except CSS selectors, maybe).

Comment: Thanks Manjula Weerasinge, I tried and it works! And i'm not Asian, not a "he", I was just searching for a solution - because i'm new to PHP and Javascript - and found one :) thanks!

Comment: It is a legitimate question and requirement for some localized versions i.e. Urdu, Arabic, Persian, Punjabi version etc. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
<label for="myInput">Input stuff</label>
<input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput"/>
```

Change it to this:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput"/>
<label for="myInput">Input stuff</label>
```

Unless you're talking about something completely different.

Answer (score -2):

lol. "its almost impossible" lol

all you have to do is in the code, place the form input type on the left, and after the closing ">" of that field, just add the descriptive text you need.....like this

```
<input type="text" value =" what ever here etc "> the text you want to the right here.
```

is this what you mean? if nto then try to be a bit clearer on your question.

Comment: no, it is not immpoible, thanks for your help, I already had the solution!